# Kivy Buttons- Sound playing on execute, rather than on click

Tags: python, audio, kivy

Me again, here is my code, why is "beep.wav" playing when I launch the application rather than when I press the buttons I assume I have bound it to?

```
import kivy
import random
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

sound = SoundLoader.load('beep.wav')

red = [1,0,0,1]
green = [0,1,0,1]
blue =  [0,0,1,1]
purple = [1,0,1,1]

class A_Cool_Program(App):
    def Orientation(self, orient):
        self.orient = orient

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(padding=0, orientation=self.orient)
        colors = [red, green, blue, purple]

        for i in range(5):
            btn = Button(text="Test Button %s" % (i+1), background_color=random.choice(colors))
            layout.add_widget(btn)
            sound = SoundLoader.load('beep.wav')
            btn.bind(on_press=sound.play())
        return layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = A_Cool_Program()
    app.Orientation(orient="vertical")
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> btn.bind(on_press=sound.play())

This line calls the function, just as you should always expect when you use the function call syntax - you called `sound.play()`, therefore the function is called and you hear the sound. The `bind` method doesn't know about any of this, it only sees the return value of the function, which is probably just `None`.

I think in this case you want instead something like

```
btn.bind(on_press=lambda *args: sound.play())
```

This passes in a lambda function, and when *that* function is called then `sound.play()` is run. This example is actually unusual because `sound.play` doesn't seem to accept any arguments, but kivy bindings automatically pass at least the instance of the button, so this code uses a lambda function to eat that argument.

You normally could just do:

```
def some_function(*args):
    print('the button was pressed!')

...

btn.bind(on_press=some_function)
```

Note the lack of brackets to actually call `some_function`. It will be called later when the button is pressed.